# Django searchable drop down for ForeignKey widget

Tags: python, django

in my Django model I have a m2m relation with an intermediate model that contain the two foreign keys of the respective two models.
My problems is that, the first model may have many entries and when I associate it with other model I have a too large drop down widget in the admin.

The default ManyToManyField widget (with filter_horizontal set) may be ok, but it is compatible only with m2m relations....

Is there a solution (even 3rd parts) for the ForeignKeyFields?
Any suggestions?

Edit:
For the other users, I've solved my problem using **django-selectable**
http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8.X/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd party component [Django Ajax Selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried with Django Ajax Selects but, maybe with intermediate m2m model don't works...

Answer (score 0):

I played around with `django-selectable` as well, but found `django-autocomplete-light` (https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light‎) easier to use and more flexible for what I wanted to achieve.

Perhaps it can be useful to you as well.